# How to find the equation on a log-log scale plot (in R)?

Tags: regression, logarithm

I have plotted about 40 000 polygons (topographic depression dataset `data`) according to their area and volume (see plot below) by the code below:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = area, y = volume)) +
  geom_point(shape = 1, size = 1.5)+
  scale_x_log10(breaks = c(1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000), labels = c("1000", "10000", "100000", "1000000", "10000000"), limits = c(1000, 2000000)) +
  scale_y_log10(breaks = c(1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000), labels = c("1", "10", "100", "1000", "10000", "100000", "1000000", "10000000"), limits = c(1, 2000000)) +
  labs(x = "Depression area (m²)", y = "Volume (m³)") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image: plot volume-areaplot]

I chose to convert both the axis to log scale. A linear model can be found by

```
lmeq <- lm(volume~area, data)
summary(lmeq)

Call:
lm(formula = volume ~ area, data = data)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q Median      3Q     Max 
-178498     -18     762   1020 1452698

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -1.490e+03  6.345e+01  -23.49  <2e-16 ***
area         4.880e-01  2.562e-03 190.52   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1


Residual standard error: 12100 on 40230 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.4743,        Adjusted R-squared:  0.4743 
F-statistic: 3.63e+04 on 1 and 40230 DF, p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

According to these results, the equation would be: `y = 0.4880*x - 1490`. Because of the double log scale, I have to convert this relationship to a power function. That would be then `y = 10^-1490 * x^0.4880`

Of course this is not realistic. I thought of making the lineair model like below:

```
lm_log <- lm(log(volume)~log(area), data)
summary(lm_log)
```

But I don't know whether this is true. Should I use just the `log` of the `log10`?

The goal is to obtain the equation to know the volume of the depression for a certain depression area. Anyone suggestions?
Thank you!

Comment: The log-log plot is a good start; but physical and geometrical considerations suggest plotting the cube root of the volume against the square root of the area: not only should this be linear, *it should be homoscedastic* -- that is, the variation in vertical spreads with with area should be approximately constant.  For regression purposes this would be superior to a log-log regression.

Answer (score 1):

I'd expect as a first approximation a power law (power function) linking volume $V$ and area $A$ of the form

$$ V = cA^b$$

so that

$$ \ln V = \ln c + b \ln A$$

so that if you regress $\ln V$ on $\ln A$ you can recover $b$ as the coefficient on $\ln A$ and $c$ from exponeniating the intercept in that regression.

From your graph there is some heteroscedasticity, which doesn't seem troubling to me with such a sample size.

Geomorphologically it will be interesting to compare the power with the isometric reference $3/2$, which is unlikely to be a good summary, as I doubt mean depth is proportional to the square root of area.

How to do this in R is surely within your reach, but otherwise off-topic here.

See https://doi.org/10.1130/0016-7606(1977)88%3C1199:ACOLDA%3E2.0.CO;2 for a personal but representative sampling of this approach.

Comment: I suspect one can make the heteroscedasticity disappear with appropriate power transformations of each variable separately, which would be a pleasant improvement.  (See my comment to the question).

Comment: @whuber It would be interesting to try that.